# How do I prevent default behavior of link click for the first 4 click

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a link points to external url. What I want to archive is to not redirect to the link for the first 4 clicks, but at the fifth click.

I know I can use

`e.preventDefault()` to prevent the redirection happens, but the question is how could I resume the normal behaviour at the 5th click? (To go to that specified link)

I have created a simple code snippet to demonstrate what I want to accomplish.

https://jsfiddle.net/fuyi/k62oo6uu/

```js
$('a').click(function(e){ console.log('event captured'); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">A link</a>
```

Comment: cache number of clicks outside your callback handler and only call `preventDefault` if `length` is below your limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside a closure you can have a variable keeping track on the number of time it was clicked.

For instance :

```
node.addEventListener("click", (function () {

    let nbOfClicks = 0;

    return function (e) {
        if (nbOfClicks < 4) {
              nbOfClicks = nbOfClicks + 1;
              e.preventDeault();
              //do stuff
        } else {
              // do not prevent click, do stuff
        }
    };    

} ()), false);
```

The var **nbOfClicks** is only accessible inside the IIFE. The IIFE returns the handler for the event and can access the variable to read / update its value.

Please note that this works for exactly **one** DOM element.

If you want to use it for a collection, and I think this closer to your problem : *on each link, prevent default behavior on click exactly four times, otherwise allow default behavior*.

In this case you have something like :

```
$("a").each(function () {

   this.addEventListener("click", (function () {

       let nbOfClicks = 0;

        return function (e) {
            if (nbOfClicks < 4) {
                nbOfClicks = nbOfClicks + 1;
                e.preventDeault();
                //do stuff
             } else {
                // do not prevent click, do stuff
             }
         };    

    } ()), false);

});
```

Because the *this* lexical context is bound to the current DOM Element when you loop over a jQuery collection.

Of course there are tradeoffs, because if you have huge numbers of links then you just looped over your entire collection and created a closure for each, which is quite expensive (both the selection and the closures). You may need to look up *event delegation*.

If you want a more refined solution when you can decide precisely what to do you may want to think about a generic handler function which would like this :

```
function handleClick (nbOfTimes, e) {

    if (nbOfTimes > 4) { // 4 being a magic number, but anykind  of condition could go there, 
                         //also don't forget that you can access the target nodes via e.target

    }

    // then you should return some kind of data indicating
    // what to do afert, like event unbinding, redirection (careful XSS) and so on...

    return { unbindEvent: true, redirect: false};
}
```

In the end you have the more generic version of this :

```
$("a").each(function () {

   this.addEventListener("click", (function () {

       let nbOfClicks = 0;

        return function (e) {
            nbOfClicks = nbOfClicks + 1;
            let {unbindEvent, redirect} = handleClick(nbOfClicks, e);

            if (unbindEvent === true) {
                 // do stuff
            }

            if (redirect === true) {
                 // do stuff
            }
         };    

    } ()), false);

});
```

From reading the comments, it appears that what you want is a debounce, in this case if we take the second example we have

```
$("a").each(function () {

   this.addEventListener("click", (function () {

       let lastClickStamp = 0;

        return function (e) {
            if (lastClickStamp === 0) { 
                // first click ever
                // or since a long period of time
                lastClickStamp = e.timeStamp;

                // trigger your httprequest
             } else {
                let diff = e.timeStamp - lastClickStamp;
                if (diff > threshold) { 
                    // threshold is your debouncing value,
                    // which sets the rate at which your events
                    // wil be processed

                    // here you exceed the threshold so you can take 
                    // action, but you need to update the last time 
                    // your function was called

                    lastClickStamp = e.timeStamp;


                } else { 
                    // you called the function before enough 
                    //time elapsed 
                    // so you do nothing 
                }
             }
         };    

    } ()), false);

});
```

For reference, I suggest looking at lodash.debounce function and for more advanced stuff to Observables and the debounce operator in a library like RxJS for instance (or xstream, most.js...).

There is also the throttle operation you could look at (in lodash and Observables).

Please ask if you need more details.

The conclusion is : use the power of JS closures !

Comment: Thanks for the concise and complete explanation with code example, this it definitely the beset answer!

Comment: I looked into the lodash debounce function, I can't figure out how to "resume" default behaviour, in this case, go to the link at the tail of debounced time

Comment: Or in your last code snippet, when diff > threshold, how can I trigger the default event behavior to go to the link?

Comment: And also in your last code snippet, since you invoke the closure function directly, would it create a new callback function for each link click? maybe need to move the closure creation out of the event handler, so it creates only once?

Comment: Hello, for your first question I think you want to look at the *trailing* optional argument.
For the second one, I think you should create a generic function which takes the event as argument and implements the generic behavior. Then you can call it whenever you want.
For the last one, yes it does create new closures for each links, this is why I mentioned looking at *event delegation*. I will update my post during the afternoon with a jQuery related example.

Answer (score 0):

You could count the clicks and then unbind the event. For example:

```
var click_count = 0;
$('.myelement').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ++click_count;

    if (click_count === 4) {
        $(this).unbind('click');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('a').click(function(e){ 
  var times = parseInt($(this).data("times"));
  if (isNaN(times)) times=0;
  times++;
  $(this).data("times",times)
  console.log('event captured',times); 

  if (times<5) e.preventDefault(); // change to !=5 to only allow 5th click
  else console.log("HURRAH");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">A link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, this should make it. One followup question then, what if the link is clicked mutiple times, but I only want to go to the link once?

Comment: Let me clarify , I don't want to go to the link at the fifth click, I want to detect if a user have clicked the link multiple times, if so, only go to the link once after use stops clicking

Comment: That is not what your question says. So what exactly can I do and can I not do when I go to your site? Click once is not enough or is it?

Comment: It goes to the site, but if mutiple times the link is clicked, I only want to trigger one http request

Comment: What you want is a debounce, I will update my answer.